# Azure Bot Framework bot does not reply often in Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I created Azure Bot Framework bot using REST API.

Bot replies in Web Chat all the time but the bot does not reply in Teams often. (Bot reply in Teams sometimes but very unstable)

When bot does not reply in Teams, it seems no messaging endpoint access in server log. Might it be a channel problem?

I added channel of Microsot Teams and I also tried adding channel of Skype before adding channel fo Teams like the article below but I got same problem still.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/cb4bbbfd-8202-4c12-bd2d-9e1f02bffcb5/botframework-azure-web-app-bot-dose-not-repry-from-microsoft?forum=windowsazureja

Tested like this

```
    curl -X POST {serviceUrl}v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId} -H 'Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type":"message","from":{"id":"...","name":"..."},"conversation":{"conversationType":"personal","id":"..."},"recipient":{"id":"...","name":"...","aadObjectId":"..."},"replyToId":"...","text":"Hello"}'
```

Comment: Could you please share your Bot id?

Comment: are you using Teams Free or Teams paid service?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, Bot ID is 2153f4ad-08b4-4bc7-bb8b-f0e356fe7342.

Comment: Thank you, Teams is Free Account, Bot service is F0, Account is Free trial subscription. I am developing using REST API (Not Azure server)...  This issue is because of these free service? Paid service is stable??

Comment: Yes paid service is stable. I had the same issue with MS Teams Free service, and opened an issue on github which has not yet been addressed by the bot framework team. Link to the issue is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/3)

Comment: oh... I had never thought this issue comes from MS Teams free service. I will try check later. Thank you @desflan

Comment: @Tomoya - Your bot is responding to me. Could you please let us know if you are still facing this issue?

Comment: After I upgraded to MS Teams paid service, this issue was not occured. It was only issue when I use MS Teams free like desflan mentioned. Thank you for confirming this issue @Wajeed-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

After I upgraded to MS Teams paid service, then this issue was solved. This was only issue when I use MS Teams free service.